# SP2013 FBA pack - returns error for User Management

Tags: 2013, forms-authentication

I dowloaded SP2013 FBA pack from [here](http://sharepoint2013fba.codeplex.com/), and I installed it.
The installation works well, I have now the FBA features.
But when I click on "FBA User Management", it returns the error :

> A Membership Provider has not been configured correctly. Check the web.config setttings for this web application.

I have to precise that I'm able to log both with Forms and AD.
I check the web.config files of my web app, of the Central Administration and of SecurityTokenService(STS). Everything is ok. I can't figure out why I still got this error.

Any help would be appreciated

Thanks,

Nico

Comment: I changed all string connexion method to "Integrated security". Now it works... If it can help !

Comment: This didn't work for us, could you provide that part of the connection string?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you're getting this error, but you can login with forms, then your SecurityTokenService configuration is ok, but there's an issue with your web application settings (web.config/machine.config).

One possibility is that the SecurityTokenService app pool and Web Application app pool run under different different user's, and only the SecurityTokenService app pool user has permissions to the membership database.

Double check your settings against the guide here:
http://blogs.visigo.com/chriscoulson/configuring-forms-based-authentication-in-sharepoint-2013-part-1-creating-the-membership-database/

If you continue to have issues, check your SharePoint log file after you attempt to access the SharePoint User Management page and hope that there's a helpful error message.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. The guide you've link is the one I followed. As my comment says, change web.config/machine.config with the Integrated Security in "connectionString" fixed it (I guess!). Because I checked all the config, rights on database, and evertything was ok.